# slightly performance drop when calling a function in C

Tags: c, function, performance, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I'm in the process of optimizing some simulation codes I made for my phD focusing on the following objectives:

1. Make it modular (creating libs and dividing the code into small pieces)
2. Make it run at least with the same performance as the codes that I already have.
3. Parallelize.

Currently, I'm focused on the steps 1 and 2. I'm playing with a code that integrates a nonlinear system of equations by means of the Runge-Kutta 4th order method and prints the results into an output file. This method is the core of all my other analyses and methods that I'm optimizing. So, every millisecond of running time is important, as in some cases I have to call the method millions of times.

I have two versions that I ran 10 times:

1. In the first version I define the function `duffing` to handle the nonlinear system of equations and the function `rk4` to handle 1 step of the Runge-Kutta integrator:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void *rk4(int dim, double *x, double t, double h, double *par, double *f,
          void (*edosys)(int, double *, double, double *, double *));

void duffing(int dim, double *x, double t, double *par, double *f);

int main(void) {
    // Program Parameters
    const double pi = 4 * atan(1);
    int DIM = 2;
    int nP = 1000;
    int nDiv = 1000;
    int nPar = 5;
    // Parameters
    double *par = malloc(nPar * sizeof *par);
    double *f = malloc(DIM * sizeof *f);
    double *x = malloc(DIM * sizeof *x);
    par[0] = 1.0;
    par[1] = 0.15;
    par[2] = 0.01;
    par[3] = -0.5;
    par[4] = 0.5;
    // Initial Conditions
    double t = 0.0;
    x[0] = 1.0;
    x[1] = 0.0;
    // Numerical Parameters
    double h = (2 * pi) / (nDiv * par[0]);
    // Create Output File
    FILE *output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    // Time variables
    double time_spent = 0.0;
    clock_t time_i = clock();
    // Solution
    fprintf(output, "Time x[0] x[1]\n");
    fprintf(output, "%.10lf %.10lf %.10lf\n", t, x[0], x[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < nP; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nDiv; j++) {
            rk4(DIM, x, t, h, par, f, duffing);
            t = t + h;
            fprintf(output, "%.10lf %.10lf %.10lf\n", t, x[0], x[1]);
        }
    }
    // Time Spent
    clock_t time_f = clock();
    time_spent += (double)(time_f - time_i) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
    printf("The elapsed time is %f seconds\n", time_spent);

    // Free Memory
    free(par); free(f); free(x);
}

void duffing(int dim, double *x, double t, double *par, double *f) {  
    if (dim == 2) {
        f[0] = x[1];
        f[1] = par[1]*sin(par[0] * t) - 2*par[2]*x[1] - par[3]*x[0] - par[4]*x[0]*x[0]*x[0];    
    } 
    else if (dim == 6) {
        f[0] = x[1];
        f[1] = par[1]*sin(par[0] * t) - 2*par[2]*x[1] - par[3]*x[0] - par[4]*x[0]*x[0]*x[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            f[2 + i] = x[4 + i];
            f[4 + i] = -par[3]*x[2 + i] - 3*par[4]*x[0]*x[0]*x[2 + i] - 2*par[2]*x[4 + i];
        }
    } else {
        printf("Wrong dimension (dim) or (ndim) allocated for system of equations\n");
        exit(1);
    }    
}

void *rk4(int dim, double *x, double t, double h, double *par, double *f,
          void (*edosys)(int, double *, double, double *, double *)) {
    double tmp[dim], k1[dim], k2[dim], k3[dim], k4[dim];
    // Calculate first slope
    edosys(dim, x, t, par, k1);
    // Assign next value for tmp[dim] to be inserted in the system of edos
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        tmp[i] = x[i] + 0.5 * (h * k1[i]);
    }
    // Calculate second slope
    edosys(dim, tmp, t + 0.5 * h, par, k2);
    // Assign next value for tmp[dim] to be inserted in the system of edos
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        tmp[i] = x[i] + 0.5 * (h * k2[i]);
    }
    // Calculate third slope
    edosys(dim, tmp, t + 0.5 * h, par, k3);
    // Assign next value for tmp[dim] to be inserted in the system of edos
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        tmp[i] = x[i] + h * k3[i];
    }
    // Calculate the fourth slope
    edosys(dim, tmp, t + h, par, k4);
    // Calculate the next value of x[dim]
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        x[i] = x[i] + (h/6.0) * (k1[i] + 2 * k2[i] + 2 * k3[i] + k4[i]);
    }        
}
```

The elapsed time of each run can be seen below:

```
The elapsed time is 0.718215 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.713928 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.705679 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.713959 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.707523 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.710903 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.708110 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.718513 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.706710 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.710024 seconds
```

2. The second version I defined the same `duffing` and `rk4` functions as before, and added a third function called `rk4_solution` that handles all the steps of the method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void *rk4(int dim, double *x, double t, double h, double *par, double *f,
          void (*edosys)(int, double *, double, double *, double *));
void duffing(int dim, double *x, double t, double *par, double *f);
void rk4_solution(FILE *output, double *x, double t, int dim, int np, int ndiv,
                  double *par, double *f,
                  void (*edosys)(int, double *, double, double *, double *));

int main(void) {
    // Program Parameters
    int DIM = 2;
    int nP = 1000;
    int nDiv = 1000;
    int nPar = 5;
    // Parameters
    double *par = malloc(nPar * sizeof *par);
    double *f = malloc(DIM * sizeof *f);
    double *x = malloc(DIM * sizeof *x);
    par[0] = 1.0;
    par[1] = 0.15;
    par[2] = 0.01;
    par[3] = -0.5;
    par[4] = 0.5;
    // Initial Conditions
    double t = 0.0;
    x[0] = 1.0;
    x[1] = 0.0;
    // Create Output File
    FILE *output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    // Time variables
    double time_spent = 0.0;
    clock_t time_i = clock();
    // Solution
    rk4_solution(output, x, t, DIM, nP, nDiv, par, f, duffing);
    // Time Spent
    clock_t time_f = clock();
    time_spent += (double)(time_f - time_i) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
    printf("The elapsed time is %f seconds\n", time_spent);

    // Free Memory
    free(par); free(f); free(x);
}

void duffing(int dim, double *x, double t, double *par, double *f) {
    if (dim == 2) {
        f[0] = x[1];
        f[1] = par[1]*sin(par[0] * t) - 2*par[2]*x[1] - par[3]*x[0] - par[4]*x[0]*x[0]*x[0];    
    } 
    else if (dim == 6) {
        f[0] = x[1];
        f[1] = par[1]*sin(par[0] * t) - 2*par[2]*x[1] - par[3]*x[0] - par[4]*x[0]*x[0]*x[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            f[2 + i] = x[4 + i];
            f[4 + i] = -par[3]*x[2 + i] - 3*par[4]*x[0]*x[0]*x[2 + i] - 2*par[2]*x[4 + i];
        }
    } else {
        printf("Wrong dimension (dim) or (ndim) allocated for system of equations\n");
        exit(1);
    }    
}
void *rk4(int dim, double *x, double t, double h, double *par, double *f,
          void (*edosys)(int, double *, double, double *, double *)) {
    double tmp[dim], k1[dim], k2[dim], k3[dim], k4[dim];
    // Calculate first slope
    edosys(dim, x, t, par, k1);
    // Assign next value for tmp[dim] to be inserted in the system of edos
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        tmp[i] = x[i] + 0.5 * (h * k1[i]);
    }
    // Calculate second slope
    edosys(dim, tmp, t + 0.5 * h, par, k2);
    // Assign next value for tmp[dim] to be inserted in the system of edos
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        tmp[i] = x[i] + 0.5 * (h * k2[i]);
    }
    // Calculate third slope
    edosys(dim, tmp, t + 0.5 * h, par, k3);
    // Assign next value for tmp[dim] to be inserted in the system of edos
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        tmp[i] = x[i] + h * k3[i];
    }
    // Calculate the fourth slope
    edosys(dim, tmp, t + h, par, k4);
    // Calculate the next value of x[dim]
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        x[i] = x[i] + (h/6.0) * (k1[i] + 2 * k2[i] + 2 * k3[i] + k4[i]);
    }        
}

void rk4_solution(FILE *output, double *x, double t, int dim, int np, int ndiv,
                  double *par, double *f,
                  void (*edosys)(int, double *, double, double *, double *)) {
    const double pi = 4 * atan(1);
    // Numerical Parameters
    double h = (2 * pi) / (ndiv * par[0]);
    fprintf(output, "Time x[0] x[1]\n");
    fprintf(output, "%.10lf %.10lf %.10lf\n", t, x[0], x[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < np; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ndiv; j++) {
            rk4(dim, x, t, h, par, f, edosys);
            t = t + h;
            fprintf(output, "%.10lf %.10lf %.10lf\n", t, x[0], x[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

By adding the third function, the running times slightly changed to:

```
The elapsed time is 0.753674 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.748255 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.738883 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.738666 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.736813 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.740047 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.736575 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.739985 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.737410 seconds
The elapsed time is 0.738836 seconds
```

Could someone help me understanding why this is happening and how to avoid it as I'm doing basically the same operations in the two versions of the code?

This result was very concerning to me, so I tested the same thing in a slightly more complex code, and it gives me a 20 second difference in average. In the end, It can affect my most complex analyses in weeks, maybe even in months.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For starters, how are you compiling it?

Comment: I assume you are running an optimized build, right?

Comment: Make tests more similar: stop recalculating `const double pi = 4 * atan(1);` and perhaps even `h`.  I would move the `clock_t time_i = clock();` to inside `rk4_solution()`.

Comment: On my system, when unoptimized the second code is running slightly longer. When optimized with `-O3` it runs *a bit* faster (but it is not very consistent).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'd expect it to be a compile time constant.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Unnecessary to rely on that expectation.  If OP is looking for time difference sources, a first step is to remove the unnecessary code differences.

Comment: there are many ways to optimize this code further. Replace trigonometric functions with lookup table - based implementations, pre-calculate the common factors in the loops (such as `3*par[4]*x[0]*x[0]`) instead of calculating it every iteration.

Comment: Considering that you added in your loops one more call/restore CPU load, you would expect to spend more time (consider parameters passing and stack restore on call return).

Comment: In case your C compiler doesn't auto inline `rk4` (optimize for size instead of speed for example), you can specify it as [an inline function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html).

Comment: I'm using Intel Classic C++ compiler with -03 optimization flag

Comment: RK4 is not an ideal choice for a research code. It is good for learning and demonstrations, but better methods are regularly used since electronic computers exist. Depending on what you want to do, using the Fehlberg 4(5) method with adaptive step sizes could be at the same times faster and more accurate, for other methods it would be better to use existing libraries. I'm not sure if RKF that has a simple "dense output" interpolation that would be needed if an equally spaced function table is desired as output.

Answer (score 0):

> ... how to avoid it as I'm doing basically the same operations in the two versions of the code?

Make them more the same.

---

Ideas with may/may not account for all time differences:

**Do not time extra code in `rk4_solution()`**

Perform timing in `k4_solution()` like that in `main()`.

```
// Return clock difference
clock_t rk4_solution(FILE *output, double *x, double t, int dim, int np, 
        int ndiv, double *par, double *f, 
        void (*edosys)(int, double *, double, double *, double *)) {

    // Do not time these
    const double pi = 4 * atan(1);
    // Numerical Parameters
    double h = (2 * pi) / (ndiv * par[0]);

    // Add 
    clock_t time_i = clock();

    fprintf(output, "Time x[0] x[1]\n");
    fprintf(output, "%.10lf %.10lf %.10lf\n", t, x[0], x[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < np; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ndiv; j++) {
            rk4(dim, x, t, h, par, f, edosys);
            t = t + h;
            fprintf(output, "%.10lf %.10lf %.10lf\n", t, x[0], x[1]);
        }
    }

    // Add 
    clock_t time_f = clock();
    return time_f - time_i;
}
```

**Use `restrict`**

Within `rk4_solution()`, pointed to data of `x, par, f` may overlap, affectioning optimization potential whereas in `main()` they are known to not overlap.

```
// void *rk4(int dim, double *x, double t, double h, 
//     double *par, double *f, 
//     void (*edosys)(int, double *, double, double *, double *))
void *rk4(int dim, double * restrict x, double t, double h,
    double * restrict par, double * restrict f, 
    void (*edosys)(int, double *, double, double *, double *))
```

---

There are numerous ways to increate performance for both methods, yet OP here seems to want to identify performance *differences*.

Comment: Hello @chux, thanks for the suggestions. Indeed I was calculating time wrongly in the second case. By applying the suggested change, it drops 0.01 seconds off the runtime in average. On the other hand, when I used `restrict` keyword it did not affect the performance at all.

Comment: @Lgcos Although interesting to delve into why there remains a 2% difference, consider spending effort into looking for improvements.  Note, the 2 sets of 10 times with dropping times hint to cache hit changes.

Comment: @Lgcos File I/O is a sinkhole of time and depend on many system things.  Are your times alike if the `fprintf()` calls removed?

Comment: Removed the `fprintf()` and there are still big differences. Average of case 1: 0.06 sec. Average of case 2: 0.1 sec.

Comment: I'm creating separate .c and .h files to handle the functions and see what happens with the runtime

Comment: Do you think storing the all the results in an array and print all of it in a file later would be better?

Comment: @Lgcos Yes, yet there are many potential optimizations.  Simply put, your time is valuable too.  Look for 1) reduced order of complexity savings then 2) linear ones.